# Regular Expressions in Python - combining two operations in re.sub

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to search through a load of text(located in the variable whole) for the word "he" this is then to be replaced by "she" 
I then want to search through the text again and replace "she" with he.
however the regular exprssions below are overiding each other - meaning in this example the text will be all "he"

My question - is there anyway of combining the regular expressions and doing both operations in one go?

```
#jackNew.heShe() == she
#jillNew.heShe() == he  

whole=re.sub(r'(?i)\bhe\b', jackNew.heShe(), whole)

whole=re.sub(r'(?i)\bshe\b', jillNew.heShe(), whole)
```

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that in [`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

```
import re
s = 'she said he was a nice girl'
re.sub('s?he', lambda m: 'he' if m.group() == 'she' else 'she', s)
```

gives

```
'he said she was a nice girl'
```

Comment: @RohitJain No idea whatcha talkin' 'bout ;) What happens in 5min grace period, stays in the grace period

Comment: Thanks, the answer works great!
Just wondering however if you could explain how the m.group() is working? IS the m automatically taken from the captured regular expression.
Sorry i havent used regular expressions or the lamda function much before.
thanks

Comment: @AlecHewitt Yes, the function gets the [`match` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) as argument, I've added the link to the docs with examples in the answer. [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function works the same way as a regular function, I just used it for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not exactly in one go, but an option is to take a different route. You can use an intermediate replacement, like: -

- Replace `"he"` with `"s@he"`
- Replace `"she"` with `"he"`
- Replace `"s@he"` with `"she"`

This will solve your issue.